# Unable to find the requested .NET Framework Data Provider (machine.config appears correct)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to create a SQL CLR project (for SQL Server 2008 R2), and get "Unable to find the requested .NET Framework Data Provider".

I have spent over an hour googling for a solution, and most seems to be that there is an extra self-terminating  entry or a missing "SqlClient Data Provider" in the machine.config file, but I have checked and handled all of that, but still get the same message

As a test, I created a new project and tried to use the Data Source Configuration Wizard to add a connection - same issue.  Note that I normally never use the Visual Studio wizards for connections (my Data Access Layer that handles all of that from code) - so this issue might have been there for a long time.  Same issue with both VS 2010 and VS 2013.  Project framework version: .NET 3.5.  Tried CPU Any and x86.

As a test, I simplified my DbProviderFactories section of all machine.config files that I could find to this (removing Oracle, SQL CE, etc.):

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
       <add name="SqlClient Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" type="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlClientFactory, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

These are my machine.config files

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config
```

Connection string:

```
Data Source=x.x.x.x;Initial Catalog=SomeDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa
```

Still no go!

Note that the connection string does not seem to matter at this point - it does not even get far enough to try connecting (the Framework Data Provider error comes up instantly).

**Need help debugging and fixing this.**

**Edit 10/11/2014**

Based on the article  VDohnal referred me to, I did this simple test:

```
try 
{
    string provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";
    DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(provider);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} created...\n", provider);

    var dt = DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, dt.Rows[i][2]);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

The provider is created without issue, followed by my providers:

```
System.Data.SqlClient created...

0: System.Data.Odbc
1: System.Data.OleDb
2: System.Data.OracleClient
3: System.Data.SqlClient
4: Devart.Data.MySql
5: System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0
```

Note that I added back my original DbProviderFactories entries, since this part is working.  Also, the exact machine.config file used is: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\machine.config

But the wizard still fails with the same error message.

As a workaround, is there a way to create a CLR project without using the database connection wizard?  I know the somename.sqlproj.user file contains the resulting connection string, but it is encrypted, so how do I add it manually?

Comment: What does your connectionstring look like?

Comment: @rene Edited and added this info.

Comment: Can you try adding that DbproviderFactories piece to your app.config/web.config directly and add thr attribute `providerName` to your connecstring with the value `System.Data.SqlClient`. Can you also enable Assembly Binding Logging and see if that shows bind failures?

Comment: @rene I tried adding the DbProviderFactories piece to the app.config directly.  Re providerName: there is no connection string yet - I am using "Add Connection" wizard, which prompts for server name, database, etc. (the connection string I gave you before was from a working CLR project written some years ago, that also has the same error now).  I turned on Assembly Binding Logging, but get nothing in the log / Fusion viewer.

Comment: Check this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/12/19/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-it-may-not-be-installed.aspx. There is code to list your available providers. Your problem is strange.

Comment: Also I would say: do not have VS 2010 and VS 2013 open at the same time on one computer, it can get you in troubles. I would try to open the project on another PC and see what happens.

Comment: @VDohnal I ran the test code from the article you referred me to - please see edits for result.

Comment: What version of .NET do you have installed, 4.5.1? Try to install 4.5.2.

Comment: @VDohal I had 4.5.1, upgraded to 4.5.2, no difference.  But I use 3.5 for these projects anyway - it is for a SQL Server 2008 R2 CLR.  Also, I just tried with my old VS 2008 (on same computer), and it works fine there.  Go figure!  I will just use VS 2008 instead for now.

Comment: Seems you will have to reinstall. It is difficult do give advice remotely in your case, something went wrong with your installation.